# PHP External functions should import current page name

Tags: php

I've a simple request for you (a trouble for me).
Currently I've created a function on a functions.php file that does the following:

```
<?php

   function active_check($page_name) {
        $check_current_name = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
        if ($page_name == $check_current_name) {
            echo "active";
        }

   }

?>
```

I've imported this function.php file on another .php file named test.php in this way:

```
<?php
  include 'functions.php';
?>
```

Then I've called the function in the test.php document in this way:

```
<?php echo active_check('test'); ?>
```

This code doesn't work. I've the "active" output only if inside the active_check parenthesis I've the word "functions". This means that the function basename(**FILE**, '.php') still read the functions.php page name, instead to read the test.php name.

How can I solve this? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Also while this is somewhat pedantic, you don't need to run echo active_check('test').  Since you already have a print statement inside the function you can just call that line as `<?php active_check('test'); ?>`

Comment: Thanks DaOgre for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ".php")
```

Instead of:

```
basename(__FILE__, '.php')
```

Because the [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) will always hold the filename in it where it is coded in.

And a quote from the manual:

> **__FILE__** The full path and filename of the file with symlinks resolved. If used **inside an include**, the **name of the included file is returned**.

BTW: You print the text in the function, so `echo active_check('test');` the echo is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, the trouble was the _FILE_...I'll remember for the next time.